# How to fetch large size pictures from Facebook Graph api

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I have write the code to fetch facebook pictures in php and upload it on our server and it is working fine, but the image which I get from facebook are smaller in size. Below is my code :

```
$user = array();

    $fb = new \Matrimony\Lib\Facebook\Facebook([
        'app_id' => $this->api_key,
        'app_secret' => $this->api_secret,
    ]);

    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper($this->redirect_login_url);    
    $facebookClient = $fb->getClient();

    try {
        $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken($this->redirect_login_url);
        $response = $fb->get('/me?fields=photos.limit(12){name, picture.type(normal)}', $accessToken);

    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        // When Graph returns an error
        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        // When validation fails or other local issues
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }

    if (isset($accessToken)) {
        // Logged in
        // Store the $accessToken in a PHP session
        // You can also set the user as "logged in" at this point
    } elseif ($helper->getError()) {
        // There was an error (user probably rejected the request)
        echo '<p>Error: ' . $helper->getError();
        echo '<p>Code: ' . $helper->getErrorCode();
        echo '<p>Reason: ' . $helper->getErrorReason();
        echo '<p>Description: ' . $helper->getErrorDescription();
        exit;
    }
    $data = $response->getDecodedBody();
```

I have saw multiple posts on this, but not single is worked for me. I have tried multiple combination with 'picture.type(normal)' For example I have used large, square instead of normal, but it's not worked.

Please if any one know the solution for this do let me know.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't tried this with stream/feed photos, but the generally accepted way of doing this is:

`http://graph.facebook.com/{ID of object}/picture`

If you want the "large" version, you would do:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/{ID of object}/picture?type=large
```

I'm not 100% sure if this would work for an actual photo (instead of a user profile picture or page profile pic), but I have a hunch it will - the only caveat is that you obviously must have a logged in user that is authorized to view the photo (unless it's public).

For album large picture replace

```
$response = $fb->get('/me?fields=photos.limit(12){name, picture.type(normal)}', $accessToken);
```

> with

```
$response = $fb->get('/me?fields=photos.limit(12){name, images.type(normal)}', $accessToken);
```

The source member is a link to the full photo, rather then a thumbnail link provided by the picture member.

Reference link: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/

Comment: Hi Ajeet, I have tried with the solution you have mentioned, but it worked only with profile picture. For other images it's not working.

Comment: Hello @MKT i update my answer Try it!  Use `images` instead of `picture`

Comment: Larges version facebook return is 200px by 200px which feels pathetic :(